# JavaScript Bluetooth Application Required Frameworks

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

I am a Javascript beginner, learning to make chrome apps. I need to make a Bluetooth application and I came accross this link on git, which is a sample code. https://github.com/mimetics/Chrome-BTconnect-App. It works fine, but I am not completely sure how it works. In particular I want to understand if it is using any javascript framework to implement this app.

A list of frameworks being used would be very helpful for me to proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you open the actual HTML file, you'll see the following:

```
<script src="deps/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="deps/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Seems pretty self-explanatory to me. It uses jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap (readme mentions that).

Please note that none of those actually are *required* to build a bluetooth app. Those are just "convenience / looks" libraries. The real magic happens with the [Chrome Apps APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index).